# Joining CSV to shapefile, only some attributes are joined, others are not (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I have a CSV with census population data and a shapefile with census tracts, a classic example where you would use a table join. For four of the files that i joined, there has been no problem besides poor data quality from the Japanese government (sigh). However for one of my files, the join is not completed, and only the data from one province is properly joined, with the tracts in other provinces not being assigned any new attributes

The problem is not mismatched key-values, as I can manually find the data when searching individual key codes, nor is it a datatype error, as both fields on the CSV and SHP are strings.
see photos for more context

Blue indicates population data was properly joined, purple means it was not
[image]

Here is a view of the attribute table of the shapefile (2005 Kanto Census tracts) and the CSV (2005 full)
As you can see, key codes match up about 1-1 between the two files (with a few exceptions because the Japanese government sucks at making and distributing census data)

[image]

On the right is what the features should look like, but instead most of them look like the feature on the left, without any of the population attributes on the bottom

[image]

Here is what the log looks like when I run the join. Most of the features are unable to be joined.

[[image: error log4]

Running MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2026)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to more easily access demographic data for Japan? The datasets given by the government are some of the worst I have ever worked with, but I can't find any other place with age data at the same resolution...

I have been stuck on this for so long.

Comment: Are the two key fields comprising of Japanese characters ? Or both have numbers? Also, do you have cases where the key values exist in the 2 files but no match is done?

Comment: @GforGIS no, they are both numbers stored as text/strings. Look at images 2 and 3 and you can see an example of them in KEY_CODE. I have gone through the key codes in excel and know for certain that they are exclusively numbers

Comment: Have you tried isolating an unjoined feature and copy/pasting the join key ID from one layer to the other? Sometimes that helps identify odd characters (it helps me with the Hawai'i datasets, for example).

Comment: Second troubleshooting idea: have you tried breaking the spatial file into pieces? Since the unjoined features are largely regionally constrained, I wonder if it could be running into some sort of shortterm memory cap during the processing?

Comment: @snow-raven I dont think this is a memory problem, qgis is only taking up 20% of my system memory, and is capable of taking up much more in my experience
I removed the features that are part of the prefecture that is successfully joined with and now my logs show this: 
0 features from input layer were successfully matched
23204 features from input layer could not be matched
Execution completed in 3.74 seconds

Comment: A far fetched idea but would it be an encoding issue? I could that better if I had the text. Or additional spaces in the columns? Would you be able to share the data? Perhaps 10-20 records that do not match from the CSV and Shapefile?

Comment: I think i got it to work, I re-exported the file from excel and somehow it fixed everything. I know it wasn't a problem of encoding because all of my other files @GforGIS didn't have this problem, despite the shapefiles all using Shift_JIS and the CSV files using UTF-8
I'm really annoyed because like this has wasted hours of my time and I still don't even know what caused my problem

Comment: Im leaving this post open in case someone still knows what the reason is. Just because the issue has been resolved doesnt mean this question has been answered.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. In my opinion you should share your comment as answer so people would know that you have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-exporting the CSV file from excel somehow fixed everything. I am still unsure what is the cause of this problem, however I think that something went wrong with the CSV and rebuilding it fixed the issue.

This does not exactly resolve this post but does provide a solution at least :|